# R: recoding income only works once (Bug or error in code?)

Tags: r

So I am trying to recode the income of my participants as some refused to answer or answered only answered in a not really usable format.

Thing is - the code works, but only directly after I write it. If I close R and open it, it just refuses to work. It only starts working again if I copy it again. My teampartner encountered the same bug. I was wondering if any of you could either find out what is wrong with my code or if you have encountered a similar bug. Would really appreciate any insight, as we have to include our code with our paper ;)

My code:

```
BTW_2021 <- BTW_2021 %>% 
  mutate(Q5 = recode(Q5, "800â,¬" = "800",
                     "Verstehe die Frage nicht" = "-",
                     "4300â,¬" = "4300",
                     "2000â,¬" = "2000",
                     "Ca. 1000â,¬" = "1000",
                     "~1.700" = "1700",
                     "1700â,¬" = "1700",
                     "Nicht regelmÃ¤ÃYig, nur sommerjob" = "-",
                     "Keine Angabe" = "-",
                     "Kein festes monatliches Einkommen" = "-",
                     "0â,¬" = "0",
                     "Keins, weil SchÃ¼ler" = "0",
                     "1500-3000â,¬" = "1500",
                     "4500â,¬" = "4500",
                     "Mindestens 350â,¬" = "350",
                     "/" = "-",
                     "NÃ¶" = "-",
                     "420â,¬ +BafÃ¶g" = "420",
                     "1.250" = "1250",
                     "1,500" = "1500",
                     "Keine Ahnung" = "-",
                     "1389,00" = "1389",
                     "450â,¬" = "450",
                     "Keins" = "0",
                     "250â,¬" = "250",
                     "k.A." = "0",
                     "3600 â,¬" = "3600",
                     "900â,¬" = "900",
                     "2400â,¬" = "2400",
                     "1.900â,¬" = "1900",
                     "0 (SchÃ¼ler)" = "0",
                     "3750â,¬" = "3750",
                     "2.400 â,¬" = "2400",
                     "BafÃ¶g (860â,¬)" = "860",
                     "5.000" = "5000",
                     "4000 â,¬"  = "4000",
                     "0â,¬" = "0",
                     "300â,¬" = "300",
                     "2.300" = "2300",
                     "40â,¬" = "40",
                     "0 (da Student)" = "0"))
```

my data:

```
> BTW_2021 <- BTW_2021 %>% 
+   select(Q5)
> dput(BTW_2021)
structure(list(Q5 = c("Bitte geben Sie Ihr monatliches Haushaltsnettoeinkommen in Euro an.", 
"{\"ImportId\":\"QID6_TEXT\"}", "900", "800â‚¬", "Verstehe die Frage nicht ", 
"400", "6000", "4600", "3700", "800", "10000", "-", "1300", "2300", 
"0", "670", "2500", "0", "-", "8500", "2700 ", "2000", "1000", 
"1500", "180", "4300â‚¬", "0.00", "1300", "450", "4000", "1100", 
"8000", "3000", "2000â‚¬", "861", "5000", "1250 ", "2600", "6000", 
"450", "1400", "450", "4800", "4900", "-", "0", "500", "2500", 
"Ca. 1000â‚¬", "1", "2400", "2500", "1700", "0", "1700â‚¬", "750", 
"450", "3400", "1300", "13000", "1400", "1400", "Nicht regelmÃ¤ÃŸig, nur sommerjob", 
"800â‚¬", "2700", "150", "2100", "8000", "0", "12000", "600", 
"450", "4000", "1000", "1500-3000â‚¬", "0", "-", "-", "2000", 
"600", "-", "0â‚¬", "0", "2531", "800", "1200", "?", "500", "1100", 
"0", "2950", "4000", "4500â‚¬", "1500", "1800", "Mindestens 350â‚¬", 
"450", "8600", "7000", "-", "750", "0", "5000", "900", "4000", 
"-", "420â‚¬ +BafÃ¶g", "2000", "-", "6000", "800", "3500", "4000", 
"3000", "4500", "400", "450", "4000", "1600", "3300", "2500", 
"1500", "815", "2800", "3500", "100", "2500", "300", "500", "1749", 
"700", "1250", "450", "1200", "700", "426", "900", "0", "0", 
"1500", "0", "1250", "1700", "700", "-", "-", "200", "4000", 
"5500", "3200", "0", "600", "1389", "5000", "-", "900", "600", 
"3100", "2000", "850", "1535", "450â‚¬", "1400", "2500", "850", 
"0", "250â‚¬", "2700", "777", "700", "5500", "-", "2350", "6000", 
"219", "3000", "3000", "0 ", "1500", "1800", "-", "0", "1900", 
"1600", "2600", "3600 â‚¬", "900â‚¬", "1200", "1000", "2700", 
"5600", "650", "1200", "450", "15000", "800", "2600", "200", 
"2.400 â‚¬", "2300", "2400", "-", "600", "0", "0", "1.900â‚¬", 
"1300", "450", "800", "800", "2000", "0", "Keine Ahnung ", "2500", 
"200", "3500", "500", "1600", "20000", "0", "-", "3750â‚¬", "2400â‚¬", 
"2800", "10000", "700", "4500", "1100", "1200", "BafÃ¶g (860â‚¬)", 
"8000", "3500", "860", "1000", "1800", "5000", "1000", "600", 
"950", "0", "3000", "4000 â‚¬", "0â‚¬", "2400", "1600", "1500", 
"900", "300â‚¬", "2500", "2300", "1700", "4500", "40â‚¬", "250", 
"0", "450", "0", "600", "2800", "1200", "1600")), row.names = c(NA, 
-261L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What OS and R version are you using? Are you also using RStudio? The problem sounds like a text encoding issue. Some of the data contains very odd characters. Changes are your code isn't being saved with the same encoding that's used for the data itself.

Comment: Windows 10, 
RStudio 2021.09.0 Build 351,

I saw an encoding Option in the Global Options, would changing that maybe help? 
The odd characters are € ^^

Comment: Are you using R 4.2? Because encoding on windows is a bit tricky. The native encoding is Latin-1. Is your data stored in Latin-1 or UTF-8? You basically want to make sure that the different encodings all match up.

Comment: Okay, so I am using R-4.1.1 and this command told me dat my data is using ASCII


 guess_encoding(BTW_2021, n_max = 10000, threshold = 0.2)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  encoding confidence
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 ASCII             1


I changed my encoding to ASCII now aswell and seems to be working (except for the two answers "Keine Ahnung" and "Verstehe die Frage nicht", but I guess there is some typo somewhere.
Thank you for your help ;)